# angularjs breadcrumbs using Icons

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs

```
<li><a href="dashboard.html"><i class="iconfa-home"></i></a> <span class="separator"></span></li>
             <li><div ncy-breadcrumb style="padding-top: 1px;"></div></li>

Controller:
data:{
          ncyBreadcrumbLabel:'<span class="iconfa-home"></span>'
       }
```

I want the breadcrumbs like when I'm on dashboard page I want home button and when I'm on some other page I want breacrumb like homebutton> 'pagename'. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible ,easy way is

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>{{Home}}</a></li>
   <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs track by $index" ng-if="breadcrumb != ''" ng-class="{ active : $last }" >
        <a ng-href="{{($last) ? 'javascript:void(0)' : '#/'+breadcrumb}}">{{breadcrumb}}</a>
   </li>
</ol>
```

you can generate breadcrum within $routeChangeSuccess event

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
   $rootScope.breadcrumbs = $location.path().split("/");
});
```